# Parse uneven XML using Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I have a XML as shown below which needs to be parsed, it has mapping between 2 elements(e.g. SAPClient_Test is mapped to SAPClient)

```
<logicalModel id="Join_1">
    <descriptions/>
    <attributes>
      <attribute id="SAPClient_Test" order="1" attributeHierarchyActive="false" displayAttribute="false">
        <descriptions defaultDescription="Client"/>
        <keyMapping columnObjectName="Join_1" columnName="SAPClient"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute id="RegionCode" order="2" attributeHierarchyActive="false" displayAttribute="false">
        <descriptions defaultDescription="First Region"/>
        <keyMapping columnObjectName="Join_1" columnName="RegionCode"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute id="CountryCode" order="3" attributeHierarchyActive="false" displayAttribute="false">
        <descriptions defaultDescription="Country Code"/>
        <keyMapping columnObjectName="Join_1" columnName="CountryCode"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute id="CountryName" order="4" attributeHierarchyActive="false" displayAttribute="false">
        <descriptions defaultDescription="Country Name"/>
        <keyMapping columnObjectName="Join_1" columnName="CountryName"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute id="Nationality" order="5" attributeHierarchyActive="false" displayAttribute="false">
        <descriptions defaultDescription="Nationality"/>
        <keyMapping columnObjectName="Join_1" columnName="Nationality"/>
      </attribute>
    </attributes>
    <calculatedAttributes/>
    <privateDataFoundation>
      <tableProxies/>
      <joins/>
      <layout>
        <shapes/>
      </layout>
    </privateDataFoundation>
    <baseMeasures/>
    <calculatedMeasures/>
    <restrictedMeasures/>
    <localDimensions/>
  </logicalModel>
```

expected results should be mapping between element i.e. SAPClient_Test -->Client, RegionCode --> First Region

Below is the code(naive) but i am not getting expected result .

```
tree = parsefilepath.xml # put the file to be parsed
root = tree.getroot()  # Get the parsed data of the root
Leafs = []  # Leaf Data # Define a list

def tables_tag_fro(v_root):
    for item in v_root:    
       
        if 'logicalModel' in item.tag:
            print(item.attrib)
            for origin in v_root.iter():
                if 'mapping' in origin.tag:
                    print(origin.attrib['target'], '--->', origin.attrib['source'])
                    # print(origin)
                # print(origin)
                if len(item) > 0:
                    tables_tag_fro(item)
            else:
                Leafs.append(item.attrib)
                tables_tag_fro(item)


tables_tag_fro(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use xpath with lxml instead of etree, a dictionary instead of a list, and simplify the whole thing a bit:

```
import lxml.html as lh
fly = """[your html above]"""

root = lh.fromstring(fly)

leafs = {}
items = root.xpath('.//attributes[./attribute//keymapping]') #this will ensure keymapping exists
for item in items:
    targets = item.xpath('./attribute/@id') #your desired information is in the attribute value of this and the next nodes
    sources = item.xpath('./attribute/descriptions/@defaultdescription')
    #targets and sources are both lists, so you need to zip through them:
    for target,source in zip(targets,sources):
        leafs[target]=source #add each couple to the dictionary
for target, source in leafs.items():
    print(target, '--->',source)
```

Output:

```
SAPClient_Test ---> Client
RegionCode ---> First Region
CountryCode ---> Country Code
CountryName ---> Country Name
Nationality ---> Nationality
```